how to use flutter bloc state management efficiently
I'm relatively new to flutter bloc management, earlier I was using Provider state management, I have one question regarding flutter bloc state
Let's assume I'm using Bloc for User related operations or features
There could be following states for User Bloc
abstract class UserState {}

class UserInitialState extends UserState {}

class UserLoadingState extends UserState {}

class UserLoadedState extends UserState {
  final UserModel userModel;
  UserLoadedState({required this.userModel});
}

class UserErrorState extends UserState {
  final String error;
  UserErrorState({required this.error});
}

class UserInvalidFormErrorState extends UserState {
  final String error;
  UserErrorState({required this.error});
}


I emit "UserInvalidFormErrorState" state when user is updating their profile detail and some error appear up due to form validation
the problem is that if I emit "UserInvalidFormErrorState" state, the UserLoadedState is no longer available in the screen where I'm displaying user detail
how to tackle this problem

I suggest you change the structure of your UserLoadedState by combining user data and error messages.
abstract class UserState {}

class UserLoadedState extends UserState {
  final UserModel userModel;
  final String? error;  // Optional error message

  UserLoadedState({
    required this.userModel,
    this.error,
  });
}

With this structure it avoid you changing the error state when there is a problem with the validation form.
You simply emit a new instance of UserLoadedState with the user information and possibly accompanied by a message error if there is any
void updateUserDetails(UserModel userModel) async {
  try {
    yourValidateUserData(userModel);
    emit(UserLoadedState(userModel: userModel)); // emit without error
  } catch (e) {
    emit(UserLoadedState(userModel: userModel, error: e.toString())); // emit with error
  }
}

And on the UI side you check if there is an error message in the UserLoadedState state, you display if necessary while keeping the user data

That's a nice workaround! Thanks :) but just wondering if this is the best practise to do it this way

In my opinion, yes, because this approach allows your state to integrate various types of information, which will make your application able to handle complex scenarios without losing crucial data. In addition, it will allow you to display user data even if you have mistake, thus avoiding the blank screen or changing context.
